# fullPage.js parallax scrolling through slides

Tags: parallax, fullpage.js

Is there any way I can achieve "parallax" effect when scrolling.

Im using **[this](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)**

Or maybe any different script to achieve full page scrolling (with navigation) and parallax effect.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
What im really trying to do is this effect - **[here](http://www.buildinamsterdam.com/)**

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE March 2017

Now there's a [Parallax fullPage.js extension](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/parallax.html) that provides such effect.

## UPDATE November 2014

---

Now fullPage.js provides a new option `scrollBar` that when sets to `true` allows fullPage.js to be used with any parallax plugin as well as any other plugin using the `scrollTop` position as a reference for their effects.

This is due to the fact that when using `scrollBar:true` fullpage.js is actually scrolling the site by using the jQuery method `scrollTo` which is applied to the browser's scrolling.

An example is available [here](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html).

## Original answer

There's a way, please check out this topic in fullpage.js issues forum:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/203

Here you have a site using fullpage.js with some paralax effects:
http://www.saltaboombox.com.ar/

Just take into account that fullpage.js doesn't fire the `scroll` event, it is not scrolling but changing the `top` or `translate3d` property of the fullpage wrapper.

Comment: Have you tried it using `scrollBar: true`? Can you provide a link where we can see the reproduction of the problem?

Comment: I did, but seems like the plugin isn't working via scrollTop, reason why I tried [another parallax alternative](http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/), which it worked.

Comment: is there a workaround to use the parallax effect without having to activate `scrollBar`? Otherwise IE won't work when trying to scroll within sections.

Comment: @Fabián `scrollBar:true` works even in IE 8. Don't know what are you talking about. Your problem is totally different. Avoid using `scrollOverflow:true` and it will be fine.

Comment: As I said, that's another problem, its is not a bug of `scrollBar`. The plugin is not suppose to be used in that way. Do not use `scrollOverflow` to fix it.

Comment: The idea is to activate `scrollOverflow` when screen is smaller and the entire text doesn't fit the screen. `scrollBar` would be to make parallax work. The problem is that if I activate both, I can't scroll inside sections in IE. And if I deactivate **scrollBar** it'll solve IE's problem, but parallax remains sticky in the background and useless.

Comment: Use the `responsive` option instead and [force the height of the section to be automatic](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/1044)

Comment: the http://www.saltaboombox.com.ar/ is a good example but it does not use any plugin. it has a custom parallaxSite that fires when you do a "one page scroll" and animates everything with TweenMax plugin statically